# EntityFrameworkCore with Dotnet.core

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have a database called Fruit in my sqlserver. I would like to create a C# console application (.net core) to access the data and save it as user enter data in.
I have a class called Fruits and a dbContext called FruitDbContext which stores dbSet
How do I create a dependency injection so that I can easily save my model to different databases easily? Currently, I would like to focus just on Microsoft SQL Server only and not worry about other database.

My Fruit class:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1.Entity
{
    public class Fruit
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string FruitName { get; set; }
        public string FruitColor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My FruitDbContext class

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.Entity
{
    public class FruitDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionBuilder)
        {
            optionBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server = xxx; Database=Test; Integrated Security = True");
        }
    }
}
```

My main program: My intention is just to initiate and populate my existing database with some seed records

```
using ConsoleApp1.Entity;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new FruitDbContext())
            {
                db.Fruits.AddRange(new Fruit { FruitName = "Orange", FruitColor = "Green" },
                    new Fruit { FruitName = "Banana", FruitColor = "Yellow" });
                var count=db.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine($"{count} records added");
                foreach (var f in db.Fruits)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Name -{f.FruitName}\t\t Color - {f.FruitColor}");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to saveChanges: I have encountered the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Fruits'.
```

I probably understand what the complaining is about but I do not know how to fix it properly as I am new to entityframeworkcore. If you have done ton of work on entity framework and could give me some hint, it would be highly appreciated.

This is my project.json

```
{
    "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "type": "platform",
            "version": "1.0.1"
        }
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    },
    "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final"
    },
    "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

The structure of my project is simple:

[image]

What do I need to do to fix the issue?
**Update:**

My Table in SQL

```
USE [Test]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Fruit]    Script Date: 4/16/2017 10:53:45 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fruit](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [FruitName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FruitColor] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Fruit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Do you have a database table called 'Fruits'?

Comment: No, I have a table called Fruit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the name of your property, `public DbSet<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }`, matches the name of your table. So the table should be called `Fruits` as well, or you should change the property name to match the table name.